# How to prevent LeafletJS from issuing multiple click events on overlapping markers?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I have a LeafletJS map with **a lot** of markers on it, and many of them overlap at high zoom levels.  Currently, when I click on a few overlapping markers, multiple click events are being issued, each of which then issues a `popupopen` event which in turn does a `$.getJSON()` to populate the popup.  Obviously, this isn't ideal, so I'd like to find out how to get Leaflet to just execute one click at a time.

Other answers I find on here talk about `e.preventDefault()` or `e.stopPropagation()`.  Neither of those appear to be available in Leaflet's `click` or `popupopen` events, so I'm thinking there must be a smarter way that I've not heard of.

Here's my code, watered down for the purpose of this question:

```
var geojson_options = {
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
        layer.bindPopup('<img src="/spinner.gif" />');
        layer.on("popupopen", function(e){
            // e.preventDefault and e.stopPropogating don't exist
            $.getJSON("some-url.json", function(json){
               e.popup.setContent("Some processing of the json");
            });
        });
    },
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
      // Irrelevant stuff
    }
};

L.geoJson(geojson_data, geojson_options);
```

I've tried variations on using `layer.on("click", ...)` to set a variable called `popping_open` to `true` to keep state while the popup is opening, but that didn't work either.  Tell me there's a clean way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called `OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet` that spreads overlapping markers on an onClick event so their identification is more easy. You can see a demo [here](http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet/demo.html) and download it from [github](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier-Leaflet). Maybe it is useful for your application.

Comment: I'm aware of that plugin, but it's not helpful for me in this case as it's quite possible that you could have 300+ overlapping markers.  I don't want to spider out, I just want Leaflet to not send the `click` event to more than one marker at a time.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the issue here, if I'm understanding correctly, is that when you try to click on a marker, the click event is being triggered by multiple markers that overlap instead of being triggered by the intended marker.  The only way I know to fix this is to separate the markers before the click event can be triggered.  You can do this by using a plugin as suggested, or by preventing popups from opening at specific zoom levels.

I recommend using a plugin called Leaflet.markercluster (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster).  It creates clusters of overlapping markers that separate as you zoom in.  Clicking on a cluster will zoom to the geographic bounds of the cluster, showing markers individually as long as they don't overlap.  You could use the plugin with this basic format:

```
var markerClusterLayer = L.markerClusterGroup();

var geojson_options = {
onEachFeature: function(feature, layer){
    layer.bindPopup(your popup content goes here);

    ... other stuff you want to do ...

    markerClusterLayer.addLayer(layer);
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm aware of Markercluster, but I don't want to cluster my markers in this case, so it's of no use to me.  What I want is a way to prevent the click event from firing multiple times when I click on overlapping markers.

Comment: Well, you might want to try animating the markers on hover then.  That way you can be sure which marker you're clicking instead of clicking on a group and triggering multiple events.  You can find a marker bounce plugin located here: [link](https://github.com/maximeh/leaflet.bouncemarker).  I'm not clear on why you would have so many markers overlapping by default - it makes it a very difficult experience for the user that way.